# python downloading is extremely slow

Tags: python

Is there a way to improve url download speed on Python?

I have a program that I wrote in VB6 that smokes Python without trying.  I've converted the thing over and I'm trying it out right now and the things seems much slower in Python(linux), twice as long.  Even the initial version of the program seemed like it was taking longer than what I was use to it taking on Windows.

I've tried using both `urllib`(2.7), `urllib.request`(3.3), and `requests`.  Currently I'm trying `urllib3` and it isn't any faster either.  What would normally take 45 minutes on Windows looks like it would take close to 2  hours on linux to accomplish the same task on the same computer on the same internet connection.  The task is simply searching the internet and downloading files when the search finds what it is looking for...simply a span of potential file names.

I'll also ask since it has happened more than once so far this afternoon, how do I detect a 110 error code(connection timed out).  What I'm using below doesn't work and it has still killed the program.

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def dl_10(self):
        self.NxtNum10 = int(self.HiStr10)
        while self.NxtNum10 < int(self.HiStr10)+9999:
                url = 'http://www.example.com/videos/encoded/'+str(self.NxtNum10)+'.mp4'
                r = http.request('GET', url)
                if r.status==404:
                        self.NxtNum10 +=1
                        continue
                elif r.status==110:
                        continue
                else:
                        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,str(self.NxtNum10)+'_1.mp4')
                        statinfo = os.stat(str(self.NxtNum10)+'_1.mp4')
                        if statinfo.st_size<10000:
                                os.remove(str(self.NxtNum10)+'_1.mp4')
                        else:
                                self.End10 = self.NxtNum10
                self.NxtNum10 +=1

        self.counter +=1
        self.NxtNum10 = 'FINISHED'
```

This is being run through threads, I wouldn't think that should make any difference.  Like I said the initial write up using urllib(2.7) was slow as well and it wasn't using threads I was just running the program 10 times just like I always have on Windows.

Is there any faster way of grabbing stuff from the internet with Python?

Comment: Are you talking about total time, or individual time? It looks to me like you are downloading sequentially, rather than in parallel.

Comment: I have 10 separate threecks through 10,000 files sequentially. Each program on Windows(VB6) typically takes 45-50 minutes to complete a full cycle(with all 10 running at once).  On linux/Python in one hour I was only able to get through just over 3000 files per thread.  Hence why I'm shocked by the lack of speed.  The only things that have changed are Windows to Linux and VB6 to Python.  Everything else is the same.  I was going to try the Python on Windows last night.  I got fed up with trying to install the modules and gave up.  Linux is FAR superior for using Python.

Comment: Yes, I can see from your style there that you are more familiar with VB. ;) I can't really tell what's happening from here, but you might try pycurl (python wrapper for libcurl) instead.

Comment: I want to check the website for video files.  If it exists, downloaded it and proceed to check the next possible file.  With Python 2.7/urllib it would download any 404 missing file and I would delete it.  In 3.3 it would pop up the 404 error everytime.  I started checking for the code and kicked it out as I moved through the different modules and I gained a better understanding of the modules abilities.  It won't pick up error 110, connection timed out errors though. I'll take a look at pycurl.  Heading back to 2.7.  Think I'm done with any Python 3.0+.  Too many things missing/unavailable.

Comment: Just tried pycurl and it's the same.  I'm stumped as to why I can't get the same download speed that I can get with whichever Windows or VB6.

Comment: So are you dual booting?

Comment: I'm running Linux Cinnamon Mint 15 and Windows 7.  Booted separately, not vmwareplayer or virtualplayer.  Actually on Windows 7 I do use vmwareplayer to run Win XP at the same time I'm running Windows 7 but I run Linux straight and not through one of the vm's.  I'm not sure which concept 'dual boot' actually means but I know I better play it safe when answering.

Answer (score 5):

I find that instead of using urlretrieve directly, using the following method is much more faster:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
respHtml = resp.read()
binfile = open(filename, "wb")
binfile.write(respHtml)
binfile.close()
```

To write the file directly.Hope it can help

Comment: Does this solution download the entire file before saving?  I have a long list of urls I want to download, but some of them timed out. I am wondering whether if those particular downloads just failed (or downloaded but are incomplete.)