# downloading with urllib.request.urlretrieve takes fixed time

Tags: python

I've notice that **urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fname_with_path)** takes 24 seconds to download any small file:

```
file1   file size: 3336
done in -24.33854389190674  

file2   file size: 19252
done in -24.332698583602905

file3   file size: 62105
done in -24.43064308166504                                

file4   file size: 52405
done in -24.39844298362732
```

While **requests.get(url)** downloads the same files way much faster

```
file1   file size: 3336
done in -0.10920000076293945 

file2   file size: 19252
done in -0.1716001033782959

file3   file size: 62105
done in -0.3120005130767822    

file4   file size: 52405
done in -0.2652003765106201
```

The question is what is the reason for urllib taking 24 seconds to download a file? And how do I fix that to make it wok faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the solution provided here: [python downloading is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196161/python-downloading-is-extremely-slow). It helped me to speed up retrieving the files through dividing the operation into stages(downloading and writing to file).