# How to accelerate download speed of a file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I am trying to download a file located on the web through `write` function with the `wb` mode. Files are being downloaded too slowly when it is compared to the speed of downloading through a web browser (as I have a high-speed internet connection). How can I accelerate the download speed? Is there a better way of handling file download?

Here is the way I use:

```
resp = session.get(download_url)
with open(package_name + '.apk', 'wb+') as local_file:
    local_file.write(resp.content)
```

I have experimented that the download speeds of `requests` and `urllib3` libraries are almost the same. Here is the experimental result to download a `15 MB` file:

- `requests`: `0:02:00.689587`
- `urllib3`: `0:02:05.833442`

p.s. My Python version is `3.7.0`, and my OS is `Windows 10 version 1903`.

p.s. I have investigated the [reportedly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196161/python-downloading-is-extremely-slow), but the answers/comments did not work.

Comment: Could you possibly provide the `download_url`?

Comment: Of course, for example, visit https://apkpure.com/true-fear-forsaken-souls-part-2/com.Goblinz.TrueFear2, then click the _Download_ button to generate and retrieve the download link. @Fozoro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python downloading is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196161/python-downloading-is-extremely-slow)

Answer (score 1):

Seems odd, but it makes sense -- the browser caches the download, where writing directly to file does not.

Consider:

```
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
temp = SpooledTemporaryFile()
resp = session.get(download_url)
temp.write(resp.content)
temp.seek(0)
with open(package_name + '.apk', 'wb') as local_file:
    local_file.write(resp.content)
```

That *may* be faster.

If you can create an asynchronous write to local file, you won't hold up your program.

```
  import asyncio
  async def write_to_local_file(name, spool_file):
      spool_file.seek(0)
      with open(package_name + '.apk', 'wb') as local_file:
          local_file.write(spool_file.read())
```

Then:

```
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
temp = SpooledTemporaryFile()
resp = session.get(download_url)
temp.write(resp.content)
asyncio.run(write_to_local_file("my_package_name", temp))
```

Comment: Getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_contextvars'` when I execute the script after importing `SpooledTemporaryFile` and `asyncio`.

Comment: @talha06 I am using python 3.7 on a Mac, what version of python what OS are you using?  Can you try each import from the python shell?

Comment: My OS is `Windows 10 (version 1903)` and the version of Python is `3.7.0` as I have declared in the OP.

Comment: @talha06 : Yes, there seems to be a known bug with contextvars and Windows.  I wonder if the code is reasonably fast without asyncio?  The Spooled Temp File should help.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I have not recognized any concrete speedup.

Comment: Perhaps threading will help:  t = threading.Thread(target=write_to_local_file, args=("my_package_name", temp, )), worth a try.

Comment: Your `async` function is not really a co-operative coroutine as the file writing operation is done synchronously.